# Changing Alias name dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

While I was working on a small task I came across a situation

```
DECLARE   @i  INT ,
    @l  INT ,
    @desc  CHAR(50)

SET    @l = 1 
SET    @i = 20
WHILE   ( @l <= @i ) 
BEGIN
  SELECT  'Test'   AS   'Test'+@l
  SET @l =   @l  +  1
END
```

In this code I want when a loop run all time column name changed with the value of @l.

Comment: What is your question? How do you dynamically select a column or something else?

Comment: @cane: How do i dynamically select a column.

Comment: Unless you use dynamic SQL (as per Mikael's answer) to construct *new* queries, you're up against a simple situation - any particular query in SQL will always return a result set with the same "shape" - that is, it will always have a particular set of columns, and each of those columns will have the same names and types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to build the statement dynamically and use [EXECUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) or [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) to execute the statement.

```
DECLARE   @i  INT ,
          @l  INT ,
          @desc  CHAR(50)

SET @l = 1 
SET @i = 20

WHILE   ( @l <= @i ) 
BEGIN
    EXEC ('SELECT  ''Test''   AS   Test'+@l)
    SET @l =   @l  +  1
END
```

Recomended reading when entering the world of dynamic SQL :[The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Using sp_executesql instead:

```
DECLARE   @i  INT ,
          @l  INT ,
          @desc  CHAR(50),
          @SQL NVARCHAR(100)

SET @l = 1 
SET @i = 20

WHILE   ( @l <= @i ) 
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT  ''Test''   AS   Test'+CAST(@l AS NVARCHAR(10))
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
    SET @l =   @l  +  1
END
```