# Using created column in select statement twice

Tags: sql, select

I have a big problem with this query in SQL.

```
select distinct 
    b.*, 
    case 
       when b.Cash > b2.Cash 
         then ((b.Cash - b2.Cash) / b.Cash) * 100 
    end as Increased, 
    ('Cash Increased by' + convert(VARCHAR(20), Increased))) as 
    Case
from 
    Accounting b
join 
   (…
```

In select statement I created column `Increased`. Then I want to created another column `Case` with the following value `Cash Increased by… (value from Increased column)`.

My question is how can I do it in one select statement?

Comment: Can you show the entire sql instead of just a part of it?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14210007/877472) might be relevant to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options

- Use this query as a subquery and do the concatenation in the outer query
- You have to copy-paste the `CASE..WHEN` into the concatenations

**Subquery**

```
SELECT
    *
    , ('Cash Increased by' + convert(VARCHAR(20), Increased))) AS CASE
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        b.*
        , CASE 
            WHEN b.Cash > b2.Cash THEN ((b.Cash - b2.Cash) / b.Cash) * 100
        END AS Increased
    FROM
        Accounting b JOIN (...)
) SubQuery
```

**Copy the CASE part**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    b.*
    , CASE 
        WHEN b.Cash > b2.Cash THEN ((b.Cash - b2.Cash) / b.Cash) * 100
    END AS Increased
    , (
        'Cash Increased by' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),
            CASE 
                WHEN b.Cash > b2.Cash THEN ((b.Cash - b2.Cash) / b.Cash) * 100
            END)
    ) AS CASE
FROM
    Accounting b JOIN (...)
```

**NOTE**
Do not forget to escape (or change) the alias for the concatenation. The `CASE` is a reserved word in most DMBS!

**NOTE 2** Next time please mention the DBMS you are using!